# Excel VBA: Get Yahoo Finance data

Tags: excel, vba

I want to build a simple spread sheet that make use of latest stock quotes from Yahoo, I tried a few samples from the web, but all failed with this error: "A connection with the server could not be established". Any idea?

---

```
Sub getQuotes2()

Dim URL As String
URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=^GSPC&f=l1"

MsgBox URL

Set Http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Http.Open "GET", URL, False
Http.send

Dim Resp As String: Resp = Http.responseText

MsgBox Resp

End Sub
```

Comment: automate IE. it will fetch you all info for you

Comment: here is a sample how to automate http://vbacodeings.blogspot.in/

Comment: Works for me => 
2051.31 are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Hi Alex, you can run my code in excel? I tried a few different code version, with minor differences, but all prompt this error. I am working in my company network, so very likely behind a proxy, not sure is it related.

Comment: Yes I just copy/paste/F5. IIRC WinHTTP does not use the default proxy by default, try [finding out](http://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using) what it is and use .SetProxy (or ask your corp net admins)

Comment: I just pasted the code into an Access DB that I happened to have open and (other than missing a `Dim HTTP as Object`) it worked just fine. ProTip: Use `Option Explicit` just to ensure you're declaring your variables - makes it nicer for everyone.